# What changes in the code if I run IE 8 debugger on a web site?

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-8, openlayers, ie-developer-tools

I have a website with OpenLayers where the map doesn't work in IE8 (it does work in IE9, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, Safari).

However, when I run the debugger tool in IE8 and just keep hitting F5 until it is done, the website suddenly works fine. The problems it identifies are solely in the OpenLayers.js, not in my script.

Now, I am really new to web development - but I always thought a debugger is not changing anything in code unless I do so manually, and if it did, I would actual see what it is doing. But IE8 just points out the problems, and then the website works.

This is the link to the website:

http://xweb.geos.ed.ac.uk/~s1148194/eq/map.html

Can someone explain this to me in simple words?

Thanks, and apologies if this question is rather stupid.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you'd specify in what way it doesn't work, but my guess is that the pause for the debugger is long enough for something to catch up, which otherwise IE8 wasn't managing to load or run in time before it was needed.

Comment: The website itself is okay, it is only the div with the map that is broken in the sense that nothing is displayed.

The IE8 debugger points out only 4 lines in the OpenLayers.js which are related to height and width as I understand. 

So it has nothing to do with catching-up, unfortunately. This is the link to the site:

http://xweb.geos.ed.ac.uk/~s1148194/eq/map.html

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly a race condition. If you have AJAX calls, the HTTP requests behind them continue running even when the script is paused, so they have a chance to complete before you hit F5 to continue. Without debugging, the script keepts running and may try to access the AJAX result before it arrives.

To fix, make sure you wait for an AJAX result to arrive before trying to use anything it contains. Alternatively (not recommended, but possible) you can make your AJAX requests synchronous. This eliminates any possibility of a race condition.